# WPF ScrollViewer in grid's column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to show the horizontal scrollbar when the width of the window is smaller than width of the text in first column.

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" >
        <TextBlock Text="Very looooong text" FontSize="30"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Red"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Green"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

What's the best way to do it?

--edit
When the user is dragging the right border of the window from right to left first I need to narrow the third column until it disappears, then I need to narrow second column until it disappears, and then when the width of window is smaller than text I need to show the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: To get a horizontal scroll bar, you need to set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on your ScrollViewer.

Comment: @sthotakura, nope, it does not work

Comment: I tried in a sample app and it works.for me. You may need to increase the fontsize to something like 50 to see the effect?

Comment: Ok, when the fontsize is bigger your solution works, but I need solution, when the text is not wider than column at the beginning. I need to show scrollbar when user change the width of the window to smaller one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the width of first column to a static value (300) so the column's width will not change when you resize the window. If you set a dynamic value, the ScrollViewer will work as you expect.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" MaxWidth="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="80"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
        <TextBlock Text="Very looooong text" FontSize="30"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Red"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Green"/>

</Grid>
```

PS: Width of ScrollViewer must be less than the TextBlock, and the scrolling will work

Comment: Ok, that's true, but I need the static value of width in the first column, or at least I need the start value 'x' which means "not wider than 'x'". In your solution the first column stretches with whole window.

Comment: Okay, i edited my answer: <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="300"/>  is the desired behavior. (also you can specify the MinWidth)

Comment: Wait, now I see that column with text becomes narrow simultaneously with the third column, which is not good. When the user is dragging the right border of window from right to left first I need to narrow the third column until it disappear, then I need to narrow second column, and then when the width of window is smaller than text I need to show the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Edited again. It will behave as you described

Comment: Ok, that's it. Thanks